# WPF - MergedDictionary using RibbonControlsLibrary in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribboncontrolslibrary

In code behind, this works:

```
 this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon.PopularApplicationSkins.Office2007Black);
```

How do I do this in xaml?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:-

```
<Window x:Class="WPFRibbon.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;assembly=RibbonControlsLibrary"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="400">

<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/RibbonControlsLibrary;component/Themes/Office2007Black.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```